# Cell data resets to null when updating grid in extjs

Tags: extjs, combobox, grid

I'm trying to edit the grid with different values, The grid is shown [image: here in this pic].

Bus name column is a combobox with a valueField as id and displayField as its name. 
now when I try to update the grid with different values except the the **Bus name** column without touching that cell (i.e updating only the **ongoing** column or timing), the Bus Name column gets updated as null in the database. But, When I update along with the Bus Name column then that works, else the record of Bus name Column in that row resets to null data. 
the Sample is [image: shown in this pic]  and [image: in this pic.]

Here I changed and updated the time the Bus Name Column  automatically got updated as null.

below is the piece of code of my grid panel Bus Name Column and plugins listeners. Please help me solve this

```
{
            text: 'Bus Distrib',
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            itemId:'gridId', 
            dataIndex: 'bus_distributor',
            flex: 1,
            renderer: function(value){
            if(Ext.isNumber(value)){
                var store = this.getEditor().getStore();
                return store.findRecord('busid',value).get('busdescription');
            }
            return value;
            },
            editor: {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                allowBlank: true,
                displayField: "busdescription",
                valueField: "busid",
                queryMode: 'local',
                mapperId: 'getbusDistrib',
                lastQuery: '',
                editable:true,
                forceSelection: true,
                readOnly: false,                         
                listeners: {

                    expand: function () {
                        var call = this.up('busGrid[itemId=busTimeGrid]').getSelectionModel().selection.record.data.networkname.trim();
                        this.store.clearFilter();
                        //this.store.filter('call',call);
                        this.store.filter({
                            property: 'call',
                            value: call,
                            exactMatch: true
                        })
                    }
                },

            },
        }

plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 1,
            listeners: {
            validateedit: function (editor, context, eOpts) {
                    if (context.field === 'bus_distributor') {
                        var store = context.column.getEditor().store,
                            record = context.record;
                        if (store.find('busid', context.value) === -1) {
                            context.cancel = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        })
    ]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle? [I have tried](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1r0u), but I get `[W] XTemplate evaluation exception: this.getEditor is not a function` and no rows are shown at all.

Comment: @Alexander you didn't add store data in your fiddle